# Query very slow despite having indices

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am using the following query which is very slow despite having indices, can someone help?

table a has close to 50k entries and table b about 2 million
i tried creating index on batchid in table 2 but it didnt help

```
select distinct x, y 
from t1 a,t2 b  
where b.batch_id = a.batch_id and b.sm_id = a.smid and b.status = 'new' and target_userid = *some value*
limit 10
```

here is the explain output

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                     | key           | key_len | ref                          | rows    | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | smreconhistory_sm_id_status_index | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                         | 2033644 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | smid_batch_id,idx_batch_id        | smid_batch_id | 16      | sync.b.sm_id,sync.b.batch_id |       1 | Using where; Distinct        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------
```

index for table 1

```
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| SMReconJobEntry |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | id          | A         |       49323 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconJobEntry |          1 | smreconjobentry_ugid_index |            1 | ugid        | A         |       49323 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconJobEntry |          1 | smid_batch_id              |            1 | smid        | A         |       49323 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconJobEntry |          1 | smid_batch_id              |            2 | batch_id    | A         |       49323 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconJobEntry |          1 | idx_batch_id               |            1 | batch_id    | A         |       49323 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--
```

for table 2

```
+----------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                          | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| SMReconHistory |          0 | PRIMARY                           |            1 | id           | A         |     2033644 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconHistory |          1 | smreconhistory_sm_id_status_index |            1 | sm_id        | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconHistory |          1 | smreconhistory_sm_id_status_index |            2 | status       | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| SMReconHistory |          1 | gmailunit_id_foreign              |            1 | gmailunit_id | A         |     2033644 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: You've omitted some crucial information, such as the table definitions.  Also, what are `*value*` and `target_userid`?  Also, I've not seen `*value*` without quotes as a valid string literal in mysql (though it's been awhile since I used mysql).

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the ***actual*** sql statement that is causing the issue.

Comment: @JimGarrison edited, target_userid is another column and value is any value i meant

Comment: Your low-cardinality index `smreconhistory_sm_id_status_index` does not contribute anything, as shown by the fact that the optimizer chose a full table scan instead of an index,  as explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1309cardinal/index.html)

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, this i have seen, should i create an index on batch_id then?

Comment: We cannot tell you, only you know the data distribution.  EXPERIMENT!!  You can find the optimal solution a lot faster than we can guess.

Comment: @JimGarrison you dont understand, i did try, i created an index on batch_id and also tried the combination of smid,batchid,status even then nothing works. Thats why i am posting here

Comment: `b.batch_id = a.batch_id and b.sm_id = a.smid`  -- table `a` has an index on `batch_id, smid`.  Why does table `b` not have one also?

Comment: @JimGarrison i did add batch_id index to table b too, but even that didnt help. thats what i was trying to convey

Answer (score 1):

Do not use find_in_set, replace function, it will calculate every time, I would suggest to  use IN  with static values.

```
x IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: that find_in_set has nothing to do with performance, because even this query is slow
select distinct x, y 
from t1 a,t2 b  
where b.batch_id = a.batch_id and b.sm_id = a.smid and b.status = 'new' and target_userid = ***
limit 10

Comment: ok, then I suspect that distinct may cause performance issue, please have a try by removing it to check the difference.

Comment: Tried that already, thats not the culprit

Comment: checked the explain output,  rows value of second row is 1, probably your index doesn't work, could you also create a multiple columns index for table2 just like table1?